# What can i do to solve this error in Python with pandas and requests?

Tags: pandas, python-requests, traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\49152\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\main.py", line 4, in \<module\>
import panda as pd
File "C:\\Users\\49152\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\panda\__init_\_.py", line 1, in \<module\>
from request import PandaRequest
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'request'
```

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

api_key = 'API_KEY'
symbol = 'AAPL'
interval = '10s'

url = f'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol={symbol}&interval={interval}&apikey={api_key}'

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()

times = []
open_prices = []
close_prices = []
high_prices = []
low_prices = []

for time, values in data['Time Series (10s)'].items():
    times.append(datetime.strptime(time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    open_prices.append(float(values['1. open']))
    close_prices.append(float(values['4. close']))
    high_prices.append(float(values['2. high']))
    low_prices.append(float(values['3. low']))

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Symbol': [symbol] * len(times),
    'Time': times,
    'Open': open_prices,
    'Close': close_prices,
    'High': high_prices,
    'Low': low_prices
})

print(df)
```

Comment: It's not `import panda as pd` but `import pandas as pd`. You have to install `pandas`

Comment: Check `pip list` here - did you install "panda" instead of "pandas"? If so, do a `pip uninstall panda`, whatever it is can't be helping

Comment: I did that but still get the same error